# Reducing my equation size in Gekko or increasing max string length in APMonitor

Tags: python, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, gekko

I am using gekko to optimize a model with hundreds of variables u_i and hundreds of equations. There are many equations of the type

```
m.Minimze(m.cos(m.sum(a_i*u_i)))
```

where a_i is just some float not dependent on the gekko model. These types of equations produce an error however:

> APM model error: string >       15000  characters
> Consider breaking up the line into multiple equations

> The may also be due to only using newline character CR
> instead of CR LF (for Windows) or LF (for MacOS/Linux)
> To fix this problem, save APM file with appropriate newline characters

Since the whole sum needs to be inside of the cos, splitting the equation is not possible. Is it possible to increase the maximum string length? [This seems to be possible somehow](https://groups.google.com/g/apmonitor/c/SJcIv41weAE), however it is not clear to me how to do it. Runtime and computational resources wouldn't be an issue here.

Another Idea would be to use Intermediate variables but it is not clear to me how exactly these are handled internally. Here the documentation gives me trouble. It would be great, if somebody could explain this to me in simpler words than the documentation and maybe even tell me, if this is a sensible approach to take.

Answer (score 0):

In Python Gekko, intermediates are defined with the Intermediate function.

```py
y = m.Intermediate(x)
```

An example of intermediates is with the equations `z=sqrt(x+y)` and `w=(x+y)**2` that both share a common `x+y` term.

```py
i = m.Intermediate(x+y)
m.Equations([z==m.sqrt(i),
             w==i**2])
```

To identify long equations, open the `gk0_model.apm` file with a text editor in the run folder `m.path` or by opening the folder with `m.open_folder()`. Naming the variables with `name='x'` such as `x = m.Var(value=1,name='x')` helps to improve the readability of the APMonitor model.